# When you change entirely to a new class after the 10th level, do you get the new class's damage die?

Tags: dungeon-world, character-advancement

When you have enough XP to go to 11th level, the book says that you can "change entirely to a new class."

The book says this about what that means (in [this section](https://acodispo.github.io/Dungeon-World-HTML-SRD/playing_the_game/), under "Beyond 10th Level"):

> Changing classes means keeping your ability scores, race, HP, and whatever moves you and the GM agree are core to who your character is. You lose all other class moves, replacing them with the starting moves of your new class.

Based on this, I wouldn't get the base HP of the new class, keeping my old HP instead.

However, I'm not sure whether I keep the damage die of my original class or take the damage die of my new class?

Here's some more context about the damage die, from the same page linked above (under "Damage"):

> If a move just says “deal damage” the character rolls **their class’s damage dice** plus any bonuses or penalties from moves, weapons, or effects. *(emphasis mine)*

So, maybe another way to ask this question could be, **when you deal damage after changing entirely to a new class after 10th level, do you roll the damage die of your original class or your new class?**

Official sources, such as comments from the developers or quotes from the book, would be appreciated in an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, you *just* have the new class's damage die.

Note that a class's playsheet just says "your base damage *is* dX." (Emphasis mine.) It doesn't say "you gain 1dX damage dice" or something like that.

True, the phrase "damage *dice*" is used in many places in the book. But note the presence of advanced moves such as the fighter's Merciless or the thief's Cheap Shot: it's not unusual for characters to roll multiple dice for damage.

Answer (score 1):

You've answered your own question here: the character is changing class, the damage dice are tied to class, and the damage dice are not explicitly listed as kept when changing class.

> Once you’ve reached 10th level things change a little. When you have enough XP to go to 11th level instead you choose one of these:
>
> - Retire to safety
> - Take on an apprentice
> - **Change entirely to a new class**

Emphasis mine.

Comment: I don't think I've answered my own question. One's damage die is not explicitly listed as kept, but it's not explicitly listed as lost either. One could, in theory, gain *both* dice as one's damage dice! For instance, if I create a Fighter and then later multiclass as above into a Wizard, I might gain the new 1d4 damage die *without* losing the original 1d10 damage die. In that case, my damage would be 1d10+1d4, keeping both and losing neither. This seems kind of silly, but I use it as an example of why I think the answer is unclear (plus, that's how my wife thinks it might work).

Comment: @CaptainDelano If you change class, you're no longer the old class.

Comment: I think Delano has a point. This answer is complete if you assume the way damage dice. But his problem is that even that part is unclear, as shown by his comment here. I don't remember well enough how the book is structured, but quoting the section on Damage Die would probably clear that up.